# TSQL: Add lines to "SELECT" result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017-express

we're using SQL Server 2017 Express and I have this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT '' as ItemId, '-- Please select --' as ItemDesc
    UNION 
    SELECT [id] as ItemId, [DisplayName] as ItemDesc 
    FROM [table] 
) as t
ORDER BY
CASE ItemDesc
    when '-- Please select --' then 1
    when 'bla' then 2
    when 'fasel' then 3
    when 'blubb' then 4
    when 'lala' then 5
    when 'duh!' then 6
    when 'spamalot' then 7
    else 8
end, ItemDesc
```

This works, but I need to add a second "static" line at pos. 8, something like

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT '' as ItemId, '-- Please select --' as ItemDesc,
     '' as ItemId, '----------' as ItemDesc
        UNION 
    ...
CASE ItemDesc
    ...
        when '----------' then 8
        else 9
```

Of course this doesn't work, but you get the idea. Unfortunately I have no access to the code which creates the list, all I could do is to add Javascript to the output.

Is this somehow possible? And does it make any sense to do this NOT using JS and manipulate the DOM?

Comment: You better do all that stuff on the client side. This is a presentation issue, not a data issue, therefor you have no business doing it on the database.

Comment: "I have no access to the code which creates the list"   Are you saying you can't modify the SQL?   If you need to do this in JavaScript, why haven't you tagged `JavaScript`?

Comment: @Tab Alleman nope, I have access to the SQL and I have access to the template, which shows the output. But I have no access to the code which generates the list (it's not part of the template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more `union` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT '' as ItemId, '-- Please select --' as ItemDesc
      UNION 
      SELECT '', '----------' 
      UNION
      SELECT [id] , [DisplayName] 
      FROM [table] 
     ) t
ORDER BY . . . ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in a new column to each SELECT in your UNION to determine sort order so you don't have to monkey around with a CASE:

```
SELECT itemid, ItemDesc FROM 
(
    SELECT '' as ItemId, '-- Please select --' as ItemDesc, 0 as mysortcolumn
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        [id] as ItemId, 
        [DisplayName] as ItemDesc, 
        CASE ItemDesc           
            when 'bla' then 1
            when 'fasel' then 2
            when 'blubb' then 3
            when 'lala' then 4
            when 'duh!' then 5
            when 'spamalot' then 6
            else 7 END as mysortcolumn 
    FROM [table] 
    UNION 
    SELECT '' as ItemId, '-- Please select --' as ItemDesc, 1000 as mysortcolumn
) as t
ORDER BY mysortcolumn asc;
```

BUT... this feels like you are trying to build a UI in your record set. Are you sure this is the place where you should be doing this logic? It's very cumbersome for a database. It feels like you should be running that ONE `SELECT` statement against `[table]` with your order by and then the two beginning and ending lines should be written by your code that builds the UI (wherever this data is being used).

Comment: yes, unfortunately I have no access to the code which builds the UI. I know this is a shitty way to change an UI.

Comment: Oddly I feel a lot better about this if we all agree it's crappy ;) I'm going to leave that last paragraph in this answer even though you are clearly on the up and up, just because I KNOW someone will stumble upon this answer in a year from now that doesn't realize how crappy it is and perhaps will maybe get a clue. (or at least save them from being shanked in the parking lot after work by the person that has to inherit their application).